# .net5 windows api calls with CSWinRT

Tags: c#, wpf, bluetooth, windows-runtime

I am using the Windows.Devices.Bluetooth library in a WPF application using the .net 5.0 framework.
I have referenced the windows api by installing the CSWinRT nuget and using the target framework moniker in my csproj file like this:

```
<TargetFramework>net5.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
```

This is instead of adding references to windows.winmd and windowsruntime.dll as you had to do pre-.net5. I am able to use the windows library with no problem, but I am also using a class library made from a different project using .net 4.7.2 which also references/uses the Windows.Devices.Bluetooth library and thats when im getting this error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS0012  The type 'BluetoothLEDevice' is defined in an assembly
> that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Windows,
> Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null,
> ContentType=WindowsRuntime'.  128 Active

So i can access the library directly but not through the dll. Maybe its a problem that the dll uses a different framework?

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: The problem is likely that you normally cannot use a dll built for .NET Framework in a .NET Core 5.0 App. This just fails in most cases. If possible, try to rebuild that other dll with .NET Core 5.0 as well (or with .nestandard2.0)

Comment: Upgrade the "different project" to .NET 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this was to upgrade the class library project .net 5 so that both projects are using the same framework.